# How do I retain my photo edits when opening the files in other apps?

Tags: ios, photos, image-editing

I just got back from our first family road trip vacation. I took about 1000 pictures and edited them each night and as we drove to our next location.
Today, when I tried to open them in other apps, the edits were gone. They still show in the *Albums*, but when the file is transferred, the original one is sent. All my work was for naught! Unless you know of somehow to have the edits stay? I'm really hoping you know of a fix for the issue. When I tried to look up a fix, I just found sites of others complaining. I'm on the latest iOS (I think is 6.0.3 or something like that). Can you help? :)

Comment: What app did you use to make edits?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using iPhoto for iOS (please clarify):

Applications can only access photos stored in your iOS device's Camera Roll. When you edit a photo in iPhoto (and likely in other, similar applications), the app creates a copy of the photo and stores it within its own storage area, where other apps can't see it. In order to make the edited photos available to other apps, iPhoto lets you export one or more of your Edited photos in a variety of ways: select one or more photos and tap the Share button to see the options, which include sending the photo to your Camera Roll (where other apps can see it) and Open In... which lets you send the photo to a specific app.

I'll admit, this is somewhat inconvenient when you have a large number of photos, as even when selecting multiple, iPhoto limits you to selecting 100 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know what application did you use to do your EDITS, it is difficult to help you.

Unfortunately there are to many photo applications out there.

The problem is that you can make edits in some but the edits are application specific and mostly not transferable to other photo app.

In simple terms, when you make an edit in one application, others my not be able to read them, but they are not lost, just have to use the original application.

To overcome some of the problem in the future do not use albums, instead use saving a single photo. The reason is the albums are made specific to a photo software and not transferable.

So to fix your problem, open the albums in the application you made the edits and save the individual photos.